# C++ Class members as array, packing failure case

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-alignment

I'm wondering if there's a concrete case that iterating over member variables of the same type using a pointer will fail?  I know member packing / padding is implementation-defined, but in the implementations I've tried (gcc, clang, and Visual Studio), I can't get it to fail.

Even cases that might be likely to fail, such as the following, it all succeeds:

```
#pragma pack(16)

struct MyStruct 
{
    char firstChar;
    char mySecondChar;
    char thirdChar;
};

class MyContainerStruct
{
public:
    uint64_t big;
    MyStruct z1;
    MyStruct z2;
} gStruct;

main()
{
    MyStruct *pStruct = &(gStruct.z1); // Start with gStruct.z1
    pStruct++;                        // Iterate to gStruct.z2
    cout << pStruct->myThirdChar;
}
```

Can anyone find a case in which iterating over class members of the same type fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler may reorder fields if they have different visibility.  It may also pad fields with any amount of space it likes for any arbitrary reason it wants (many compilers have extensions which can be used to control this behavior however).

Fields within one visibility specifier are guaranteed to be in the order in which they appear in the definition.  Visibility sections are not bound to be in any order, even if they have the same visibility as another section.

```
class A
{
public:
    int someField;      // will always be in the same order WRT someOtherField
    int someOtherField;
private:
    int anotherField;   // may be before or after someField
    int moreFields;
};
```

Comment: I believe the comment about `herp` is incorrect. 9.2/14 states that members with the same access control are allocated in order; `herp` and `anotherField` have the same access control (private) and so `herp` must be at a higher address.